# Set properties for every Instance (form,other visual object) created in class

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm playing with `vb.net` at the moment. And i'm trying to generate some `automatisation` in the setting of my `formproperties`.

Imagine I have 2 classes And 2 Forms

```
Class A
Class B
Form1
Form2
```

All the instances created of `Form1` & `Form2` created in `Class A` should recieve the following property

```
'objForm1 is an instance of Form 1
objForm1.TopMost = True
```

This works using the following logic

```
    Public Property _objForm1 As Form()
    ........ 'Some other code
    _objForm1 = New Form1()
    AddHandler _objForm1.VisibleChanged, AddressOf UpdateVisibilityProperties
    ........ 'Some other code
Private Sub UpdateVisibilityProperties(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    CType(sender, Form).TopMost = True
End Sub
```

**Now the issue/question**: `Form1` has some **other** needed properties then `Form2`. The properties of an instance of `Form1` in `ClassA` are different of those in `ClassB`. How can set the properties of every `Form1` and set other properties on every instance of `Form2` created within `ClassA` ?

**Note**: I don't want code like (as the real life situation handles dozens forms):

```
Private Sub UpdateVisibilityProperties(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    If CType(sender, Form).GetType() Is GetType(Form1) Then
       CType(sender, Form).TopMost = True
       ....
    End If
    If CType(sender, Form).GetType() Is GetType(Form2) Then
       CType(sender, Form).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Aqua
       ....
    End If
    ' Other forms may follow here
End Sub
```

**Note**: The `amount of Instances` of `Form1` or `Form2` may vary from 0 to 50 at any given time.

**Update:** I could pass the properties in the constructor but i don't want that. I want a solution that doesn't require me to alter `Form1` or `Form2`

**Update:** Inheritance isn't an option aswell. The properties set in `ClassA` for `Form1` may differ from those set in `ClassB`. Secondly writing a baseclass/interface would force me to make changes to the different forms (override methods/implement methods)

Thank you for your time

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve, or what you question might be. At first thought I wondered if Base Forms and Base Classes were a possibility.

Comment: You're looking in the right way. But using baseclasses/Interfaces would force me to overwrite/inplement the methods in the different forms, which i would like to avoid. Secondly if i use baseclasses then  the set-properties remain the same. whether Form1 is created in classA or ClassB (which i would like to avoid aswell)

Comment: since the forms can vary in several ways and there are many forms you have many, many combinations, so one size is going to be hard fit all.  Since you have different "owners" (ClassA/B), you end up possibly duplicating that code. The core common props could be set for the form(s) then have the forms query the class owner for the values they need perhaps as a Key-Value pair collection passing all values at once.

Comment: @Plutonix Your comment gave me a great idea using Key-ValuePairs :)

Comment: there is probably some subset of properties that the forms could simply figure out/set for themselves given a determinant to reduce the minutia.  `If foo=bar Then Me.TopMost = True`